# What does the phrase "roll over baby" mean in a song here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Well, I love [**this song.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp0Q6awCKyo&list=FLDUi4OEEh1WnwTT5CYPbE-Q&index=4)

From the first, the singer, Trine Rein, sings,

"Roll over baby".

I am sorry I don't get the meaning even considering the context following it.

I have my paid dictionary but I decided use to free online dictionaries, since mine is too complex.

The definition of "roll over" is, according to [**this dictionary,**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rollover)

> transitive verb
>
> 1a: to defer payment of (an obligation)
>
> b: to renegotiate the terms of (a financial agreement)
>
> 2: to place (invested funds) in a new investment of the same kind

And according to [**this dictionary,**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/roll--over)

> verb (used without object)
>
> to move along a surface by revolving or turning over and over, as a ball or a wheel.
>
> to move or be moved on wheels, as a vehicle or its occupants.
>
> SEE MORE
>   verb (used with object)
>
> to cause to move along a surface by revolving or turning over and over, as a cask, a ball, or a hoop.
>
> to move along on wheels or rollers; convey in a wheeled vehicle.

I don't understand what "roll over" means here, in connection with the following lyric "**the time has come, to make a little bit more room**".

May be, should I take the phrase literally, "roll over", in which the lover rolls his body over and around the hay or the pith of the rice(wheat, corn etc) paper tree "to make a little bit more room"?

Thank you for lifting up my interest in this song in advance(m_m).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, I'd say your assumptions are right.

For example, if I'm in the bed and tell my boyfriend to "roll over", I'm just asking him to roll to the side/another position.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular song, the phrase "roll over baby" is a metaphor.

It means "back off" and "give me some more space", "disengage" "I feel suffocated" "I need some time to myself" "I need to take a break from this relationship" and "I don't want to get married and have kids"

The message is echoed by the vision, which shows the singer alone in an empty landscape.

The literal meaning on which the metaphor is based is as you suggest: she wants her "friend" to roll over away from her.